# Keep d3 constrained to containing div

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to keep my d3 build inside it's constraining div with no success. Here's what I have so far -

```
var width = 960,
height = 570,
root;

var force = d3.layout.force()
.linkDistance(120)
.charge(-200)
.gravity(.05)
.size([width, height])
.on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("#powerchart").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
node = svg.selectAll(".node");

d3.json('/assets/images/graph.json', function(error, json) {
root = json;
update();
});

function update() {
var nodes = flatten(root),
  links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

// Restart the force layout.
force
  .nodes(nodes)
  .links(links)
  .start();

// Update links.
link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

link.exit().remove();

link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
  .attr("class", "link");

  // Update nodes.
  node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });

  node.exit().remove();

var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .on("click", click)
  .call(force.drag);

nodeEnter.append("circle")
.attr("r", 1)
.transition()
.delay(function(d, i) { return i*60; })// <-- delay as a function of i
.attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 2 || 25; });

nodeEnter.append("text")
.transition()
.delay(function(d, i) { return i*60; })// <-- delay as a function of i
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

node.select("circle")
  .style("fill", color);

}

 function tick() {
 link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
  .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
  .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
  .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

 node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}

function color(d) {
return d._children ? "#ffffff" // collapsed package
  : d.children ? "#ffffff" // expanded package
  : "#c9c9c9"; // leaf node
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag
if (d.children) {
 d._children = d.children;
 d.children = null;
} else {
d.children = d._children;
d._children = null;
}
update();
updateSide(d);
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;

function recurse(node) {
if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
nodes.push(node);
 }

 recurse(root);
 return nodes;
 }

 function updateSide(node){

$("#nodeHead").empty();
$("#nodeEmailFirst").empty();
$("#nodeEmailLast").empty();
$("#nodeHead").append(node.name);
$("#nodeEmailFirst").append(node.firstEmail + " years ago");
$("#nodeEmailLast").append(node.lastEmail + " years ago");
}
```

I am wondering I would constrain these to the parent div?

Comment: so your aim is to get the width/height from a parent div instead of hardcoding it or is the issue about your svg being bigger than the width height you give it?

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492)?

Comment: was able to get desired effect based off of what @LarsKotthoff linked , thank you lars !!!